# Use google colab to run bash code that accesses multiple files within folders and subdirectories, say program?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I mounted my google drive onto my *google colab* workspace, and ran following code:

```
!"/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/10_Conditional_Random_Fields_Dr._Richard_Tzong-Han_Tsai/project/crf++/crf_learn.exe" -p 1 -f 0 -c 10 -t simple_transition_features_template.txt train_sym.iob2 01ner.model
```

But I get the error: `[...].exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`
This was after I corrected the errorr "permission denied" by using `!chmod 755 /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Note[...]/crf_learn.exe`
Easy solution available? E.g I found that to run `.sh` on google colab, one could simply modify `!` with `!sh` to run it.

An alternative way take advantage of *colab* would be to use the folders on my local disk ( I would even prefer that) and run the .exe in the cloud.

Is there any way to use *google colab* to run bash code that accesses multiple files within folders and subdirectories?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right flags for your files?

Comment: Thanks. I just checked and I can run the program on my computer using these flags. But maybe flags must be different on google colab...